# Possible MongoDB code optimizations for multiple geonear requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geolocation

I have a collection A of around 2000 geometric objects (complex MultiPolygons, each having thousands of vertices) and a collection B of around a million coordinates. My goal is process all these million coordinates and get all the objects fom collection A that are at that location. This is the code:

```js
const location = docFromCollectionB.location;
const res = await collectionA
    .find({
        geometry: {
            $near: {
                $geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [location.longitude, location.latitude] },
                $maxDistance: 0,
                $minDistance: 0,
            },
        },
    })
    .toArray();
```

So `res` will hold a number of objects from collection A; typically between 0 and 4 in my example.

The problem is: this approach is so slow. It takes seconds to process just a 1000 of locations. When profiling the running code, I notice 99% of the time it is spending in `deserializeObject`. So my guess is that the back and forth communincation between Node and Mongo is the bottleneck here. Since there are only 2000 objects in collection A (with complex polygons), I have a hard time understanding why this geo lookup is so slow when all it should do is cache those objects when it detects multiple consecutive requests are made on the same data. But Mongo doesn't seem to do that, because it seems to keep deserializing those same objects over and over again.

I'm at the point of doing the whole geo lookup thing myself, by just pulling all the geodata to the client first and then manually processing it. But this kind of negates the whole purpose of Mongo. I've also tried firing multiple requests to the database and use `Promise.all` to wait for multiple results asynchronously, but that didn't improve things much either.

Is there anything I can do to speed up this process? Or is the only way forward to ditch Mongo and process it manually?

Thanks!

[UPDATE]

So I tried only returning the `_id` by adding a projection. This removes the `deserializeObject` bottleneck. This makes it faster, but still not acceptable. I'm still waiting seconds to process 1000 locations. When profiling, the profiler now reports spending most of the time `idleing`. So now it's the driver actually waiting for Mongo to return a result. Even when querying the exact same location consecutively, the performance gets no improvement. Now I'm wondering how Mongo has implemented their `geoNear` queries. Are they using some sort of bounding box? Even with each object containing thousands of vertices, it shouldn't take seconds to get the results of a 1000 locations, right?

Comment: deserializeObject happens on the client, not on db side. It's part of the nodejs driver, so there is nothing to cache really. And yes, serialisation is slow. There is a flamechart from another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71966751/nodeexpressmongodb-native-client-performance-issue/72264469#72264469   The only solution is to run it in parallel, 1 nodejs process per core.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I fail to understand why there is nothing to cache here. If the driver receives the same object back from Mongo, it shouldn't deserialize it again, right?

Comment: The driver does not receive an object. The driver receives a bson stream. It then deserealise it to json.  Even if the object is the same, the conditions (the query parameter) differ, so the db returns the same object each time.

Comment: And regarding the update - it must be on DB side now. You can enable profiler to check how long individual query takes.  The implementation is open https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/399e40d0f739b9c55240c0c9dc0ab61ee9a1893b/src/mongo/db/exec/geo_near.cpp if it sheds any light

Comment: You keep making assumptions about how MongoDB is doing stuff. One (often good) approach to clarifying that is to look at the open source code that @AlexBlex helpfully linked. But we can also investigate empirically. How long does a single query against collection A take? How long does `.explain("executionStats")` report? What is the ping time between app and database? 1,000 serial requests in an environment with 25 millisecond ping time is going to require at least 25 seconds just to traverse the network back and forth even if client and db processing were instantaneous